# margin-right auto is not working while using display:flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to make a navbar uisng flexbox but margin-right:auto; or margin-left:auto; is not working,bel0w are the html and css code
Html

```
   <div class="nav">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li>
                <h1 id="logo">SocialNetwork</h1>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <form  class="search">
                    <input type="text" >
                    <input type="submit" value="search">
                </form>
            </li>
            
            <li><img class="profile-photo" </li>
            <li><a id="username" href="{% %}">
                    <h3 id="user">username</h3>
                </a></li>
            
    
        </ul>
    </div>
```

css

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width:100%;   
}

.profile-photo{
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain what do you want to achieve, and what you expect from `margin-right: auto` to happen?

Comment: @Laisender i want to move one part to extreme right .

Comment: .... and which part?

Comment: @Laisender from profile photo

Comment: the margin need to be applied to the li not the img

Answer (score 0):

You can spread out items horizontally by giving the parent flex container a `justify-content: space-between;` attribute like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.profile-photo {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li>
      <h1 id="logo">SocialNetwork</h1>
    </li>

    <li>
      <form class="search">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="search">
      </form>
    </li>

    <li><img class="profile-photo" </li>
      <li>
        <a id="username" href="{% %}">
          <h3 id="user">username</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i know that but why margin: auto is not working

Comment: I would guess in a flex-container, the standard way to  arrange the items is `justify-content: flex-start;` so the items get pushed to the beginning of the container.